# How to determine which object raised event in .net

Tags: .net, events, custom-component

I'd like to create component with undefined number of sub-components within and i come across problem of handling events for these sub-components. Closer to the case i have created function for key event handling

```
void keyField_KeyDown(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::KeyEventArgs^  e) {
    ((System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^)sender)->Text = e->KeyValue->ToString();
    }
```

and i was thinking about just adding this function to every new sub-component since mechanism will be the same. But sender is component itself so the case is still open. Should i create an new class that inherites from KeyEventHandler with some kind of TAG field that will hold reference to object that actually raised the event? Will it work?
How to function delegate will look then ( i dont really understand what happens behind the event handling courtins)

The other way is to burst component which im trying to create to component that holds a sub-components that are custom-created itself and handles the problem locally, but even though i guess there have to be another way.

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is.  Yes, `sender` will be the "sub-component" that raised the event, but can't you just use `this` to get a reference to the main component that everything resides within?  Perhaps we need more details...

Comment: If you say that sender will be the sub-component then why Visual Studio creates event handler delegate with 'this' as reference for sender (changing it raise intelsense err). I cannot actually do that because at compile time i dont know how many sub-components there will be. It is like im creating a Panel inside Form and i have creator function which takes arguments passed to constructor and based on the number of these arguments it creates this much sub-components and adds it to the Panel.

Comment: "... then why Visual Studio creates event handler delegate with 'this' as reference for sender"  It doesn't.  Explain what you need to do with this delegate.

Comment: I want this one function which i presented to be valid for various sub-components, and in order to do so function itselfs needs to know which sub-component raised the event.

Comment: If you wire up all the sub-components to that same handler then `sender` **will** be the sub-component that fired that event.